# Convert float to bits in elisp

Tags: emacs, floating-point, elisp

How do I get the IEEE 754 binary representation (single or double precision) of an float in elisp.
Only thing I found sofar is this here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2002-10/msg00724.html
But I think there must be a better way?

Comment: could you explain how to do this?

Comment: It's visible in the UI. Enter `3.14` and press `d2`. I don't know the internals

Comment: For me the calc solution does not work. e.g. 3.14 yields  2#11.001000111101011100001010001111010111 but it should be 01000000010010001111010111000011 (see https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html for reference)